# Run a function every X minutes - Python

Tags: python, gtk, timer, pygtk

I'm using Python and PyGTK. I'm interested in running a certain function, which gets data from a serial port and saves it, every several minutes.

Currently, I'm using the sleep() function in the time library. In order to be able to do processing, I have my system set up like this:

```
import time
waittime = 300 # 5 minutes
while(1):
    time1 = time.time()
    readserial() # Read data from serial port
    processing() # Do stuff with serial data, including dumping it to a file
    time2 = time.time()
    processingtime = time2 - time1
    sleeptime = waittime - processingtime
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

This setup allows me to have 5 minute intervals between reading data from the serial port. My issue is that I'd like to be able to have my readserial() function pause whatever is going on every 5 minutes and be able to do things all the time instead of using the time.sleep() function.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Multithreading? Interrupts? Please keep in mind that I'm using python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do not use such loop with sleep, it will block gtk from processing any UI events, instead use gtk timer e.g.

```
def my_timer(*args):
    return True# do ur work here, but not for long

gtk.timeout_add(60*1000, my_timer) # call every min
```

Comment: Thanks. That's just the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Your callback needs to return `True` or `False` to continue or teriminate the event.

Comment: The question is old, but if someone needs to do this on Gtk+3, the function is `GLib.timeout_add(delay, function, arg)`

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly like [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309006/running-function-5-seconds-after-pygtk-widget-is-shown/1309404#1309404)

If the time is not critical to be exact to the tenth of a second, use

```
glib.timeout_add_seconds(60, ..)
```

else as above.

*timeout_add_seconds* allows the system to align timeouts to other events, in the long run reducing CPU wakeups (especially if the timeout is reocurring) and [save energy for the planet](http://gould.cx/ted/blog/Saving_the_world_one__w_at_a_time)(!)

Answer (score 5):

gtk.timeout_add appears to be deprecated, so you should use

```
def my_timer(*args):
    # Do your work here
    return True

gobject.timeout_add( 60*1000, my_timer )
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import wx
wx.CallLater(1000, my_timer)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what's going on here?