# Running function 5 seconds after pygtk widget is shown

Tags: python, function, time, pygtk

How to run function 5 seconds after pygtk widget is shown?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use **[glib.timeout_add(*interval*, *callback*, *...*)](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add)** to periodically call a function.

If the function returns *True* then it will be called again after the interval; if the function return *False* then it will not be called again.

Here is a short example of adding a timeout after a widget's *show* event:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import glib

def timer_cb():
    print "5 seconds elapsed."
    return False

def show_cb(widget, data=None):
    glib.timeout_add(5000, timer_cb)

def destroy_cb(widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

    window.connect("show", show_cb)

    window.connect("destroy", destroy_cb)

    window.show()

    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: +1 because you have actually added a link to the official documentation. People should do that more often.

Answer (score 9):

If the time is not critical to be exact to the tenth of a second, use

```
glib.timeout_add_seconds(5, ..)
```

else as above.

*timeout_add_seconds* allows the system to align timeouts to other events, in the long run reducing CPU wakeups (especially if the timeout is reocurring) and [save energy for the planet](http://gould.cx/ted/blog/Saving_the_world_one__w_at_a_time)(!)