# pygtk glib.timeout_add(): How to tell if timer not being destroyed?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

In my application I use a function to show GtkInfoBars with a timeout (as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309257/406281) thanks to glib.timeout_add_seconds().

I understand that glib.timeout_add_seconds() is supposed to set a function to be called at regular intervals until said function returns False.

I'm not doing that, but everything works as expected. It's perfectly simple. Here's my code:

```
def infobar(self, message, msgtype=gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, timeout=5):
    bar = gtk.InfoBar()
    bar.set_message_type(msgtype)
    bar.add_button(gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK)
    bar.connect("response", lambda *args: bar.hide())
    self.vb2.pack_end(bar, False, False)
    label = gtk.Label()
    label.set_markup(message)
    content = bar.get_content_area()
    content.add(label)
    label.show()
    bar.show()
    if timeout:
        glib.timeout_add_seconds(timeout, bar.hide)
```

**SO. Question time.** Look at what I did in the last line. Simply put, is this okay? Will the timeout destroy itself after the second call to bar.hide() fails? Or am I accumulating extra neutered timeouts that will wake up every 5 seconds [technically] using up resources?

---

*As an addendum:*

If, as I suspect, this is bad, and I really do need to return False to destroy the timeouts, I need some help -- I can't figure out how to play around with the code in order to satisfy these conditions: I need to allow multiple InfoBars at the same time, with each still staying connected to their own timer and button-response signal (as the code is now) **OR** I need each new InfoBar to replace any previous one (I can't figure out how to do this without inheriting the timer from the previous InfoBar--it gets messy).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Widget.hide` always returns None, which `glib.timeout_add_seconds` treats identically to False. Thus, your timer will always terminate after running once. There is a possibility that `hide` will be called twice (when the user clicks OK and at the 5 s timeout) but that's alright. So yes, your code is fine.

**Edit:** Just realised something. You're creating a new info bar every time the function runs, then only hiding it. Instead of using `hide`, use `destroy` so it gets properly cleaned up.

> ... OR I need each new InfoBar to replace any previous one (I can't figure out how to do this without inheriting the timer from the previous InfoBar--it gets messy).

It's not too complicated; just reuse the same info bar. Record the return value of `glib.timeout_add_seconds`, then while replacing the content of the info bar, kill the previous timer with [`glib.source_remove`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-remove).

There are usability trade-offs between the two choices you present (clean UI vs. making sure the user doesn't miss important info) but that's another topic and perhaps not that important.

Comment: Ah! Awesome! I'm brand new to python and gtk, so I appreciate you explaining hide vs destroy as well. And with the glib.source_remove info now I have a choice. I was wrestling with the decision -- the usability trade-off you speak of... I don't know. I'd like to find some more examples of gtk apps that use infobars. Hmm. Anyway, thanks again Johannes!

Answer (score 5):

Regarding `bar.hide` being called more than once, I think that's not happening because, as far as I know, it should be enough to return a value that is evaluated as `False` and `bar.hide` returns `None` which should be enough. However, if you want to make completely sure, you can verify with something like this:

```
import gtk, glib

def callback():
    print 'called'

glib.timeout_add_seconds(1, callback)
gtk.main()
```

In this example, the callback returns `None` as well and is called just once as you can see from the output to `stdout`.

Regarding your final question, I'd say this is already an acceptable way of having multiple infobars with a separate timer for each one. Please add more information if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks so much @jcollado! And as for your last 2 sentences: No, you're not missing anything at all. I like the result that this code accomplishes--it does just what I want; I just wasn't sure if the code itself was okay. Thanks again.