# Multithreading url requests in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Consider following problem:
I have a gtk / tk app which displays content from a website in a List(Store). I want to do the following things in order:

- display the window & start downloading
- show a progress bar
- on completion of the downloads add the data into the list(Store)

This is the condition: the user ***has*** to be able to interact with the app while it is downloading. That means that the program is in the window's mainloop during the entire download.

What does not work:

- urllib.urlopen() waits for the entire download to complete
- Popen() does not allow the communication I want between the two threads

**How to notify the program that the download has complete is the biggest question**

Since I am event driven anyway because of Tk/Gtk I might as well use signals

My preferred way of solving this would be registering an additional signal "dl_done" and sending that signal to gtk when the download has finished. Is that even possible?
Any suggestions are apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is:

- to share a Queue object between the Gtk thread and the download thread
- when a download is complete, you put the data in the queue (eg. a tuple with the
  download URL and the downloaded contents) from the download thread
- in the Gtk thread, you set up a glib timer checking periodically if something
  new is in the queue (say, every 100 milliseconds for example) thanks to the "get_nowait"
  method of the Queue object.

You can have multiple download threads, if needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052574/run-a-function-every-x-minutes-python and the queue documentation helped me, but it might be better to give a simple example.

Comment: So did you manage to do what you wanted, or do you need more help?

Comment: works :) I just thought it might be better to include a example for anyone else coming here :)